# Inheriting configuration for multiple suites

Tags: testng

I have a test package with multiple suites.  I would like all the suite definitions to inherit the parallel configuration from a global configuration xml (in particular, the `parallel` and `thread-count` attributes that are part of the suite tag).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG does not appear to support this. It does let support including `suite-files` (see [TestNG DTD](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php)) but that does not work for inheriting suite properties.

You can however parse your testng.xml files programmatically and apply what ever transform you want. e.g.:

```java
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites = new Parser("testng.xml").parseToList();
for (XmlSuite xmlSuite : xmlSuites) {
    xmlSuite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.METHODS);
    xmlSuite.setThreadCount(32);
}
testNG.setXmlSuites(xmlSuites);
testNG.run();
```

This again isn't truly inheritance. We can't really "override" the "base" values as we cannot check to see if an attribute was specified or not and then set it if unspecified because TestNG loads default values if unspecified.

To get actual inheritance you can inspect your testng.xml files directly::

```java
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
documentBuilder.setEntityResolver((publicId, systemId) -> {
    if (Parser.TESTNG_DTD_URL.equals(systemId)) {
        // return an empty DTD instead of the actual one in order to ignore default values
        return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites = new Parser("testng.xml").parseToList/*WithDTD*/();
for (XmlSuite xmlSuite : xmlSuites) {
    NamedNodeMap attributes = documentBuilder.parse/*WithoutDTD*/(xmlSuite.getFileName())
            .getDocumentElement().getAttributes();
    if (attributes.getNamedItem("parallel") == null) {
        xmlSuite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.METHODS);
    }
    if (attributes.getNamedItem("thread-count") == null) {
        xmlSuite.setThreadCount(32);
    }
}
testNG.setXmlSuites(xmlSuites);
testNG.run();
```